# Is there a way to cross check in a dictionary in Julia

Tags: dictionary, julia

I have a dictionary. It includes information about ID, the start time and end time of an event, and the coordinates of each event.

```
dt = Dict(:ID => [20, 30, 40, 50] , :Stime => [94, 142, 207, 208], :Etime => [1158, 4420, 1255, 2936],  :X => [4603895, 4601068, 4608327, 4606317],  :Y => [5809148, 5820498, 5828084, 5825361])
```

I want to cross-check the dictionary to see if two events in the dictionary have an overlapped time and a distance of less than 1000 units.

Is there a way to filter the dictionary?

Comment: What you are probably looking to use is FlexiJoins (find the package using google and study the docs). On a more principled note, Julia is a general purpose language, so of course there "is a way" to do this. What are the constraints? How big are the tables? Why not provide details crucial to answering the question?

Comment: The size of the dataframe is 964938×10, so the num of row is 964938. It takes around 10 days to run the analysis which is too long so I want to use a dictionary approach to make it faster.

Comment: I don't think the dictionary is necessarily going to be any faster. You'll probably need a custom algorithm that takes advantage of knowledge and structure present in the data to reduce the amount of pairwise comparisons you need to do.

Comment: FlexiJoins **is** the solution to your problem. You will have to read the documentation. Here is the link:  https://aplavin.github.io/FlexiJoins.jl/test/examples.html (it would be the most efficient use of your time to not wait for a simpler answer).

Comment: Thanks, I am working on it.

Comment: Definitely also have a look https://github.com/alyst/SpatialIndexing.jl  It is fast. If it works for you should be an easy and efficient solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are essentially working on a tabular data set where each `key` in your dictionary is a column name and the entries in each vector in `values` of your dictionary are a value in a column, so that e.g. the first entries of each of the vectors form a row.

If that's the case, I would recommend you actually work with a tabular data structure to make that row/columns structure explicit, e.g.:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> DataFrame(dt)
4×5 DataFrame
 Row │ Etime  ID     Stime  X        Y
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64    Int64
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────
   1 │  1158     20     94  4603895  5809148
   2 │  4420     30    142  4601068  5820498
   3 │  1255     40    207  4608327  5828084
   4 │  2936     50    208  4606317  5825361
```

Here I assume a row is what you call an "event", with an ID, a start time, end time, and X/Y coordinates. You can easily filter by events using `filter(predicate, data)`, but you have to get your `predicate` by implementing your conditions which are both non-trivial (constructing overlapping times from the `Etime` and `Stime` columns and distances from the `X` and `Y` columns).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use the filter, but the filter can only return one event, and what I want to get is pairs of events which meet the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to run the code with an estimated running time of 60 hours instead of more than 7 days. I use multithreading on HPC. The key is to freedom of data racing. I tried the Flexijoins.jl, but did not figure it out. Thanks for the other answers and comments.

```
    function func(df1, df2) # in this case, df1 = df2
    row_iter1 = eachrow(df1)
    row_iter2 = eachrow(df2)
    row_iter1.ID
    row_iter2.ID
    row_iter1.Stime
    row_iter2.Stime
    row_iter1.Etime
    row_iter2.Etime
    row_iter1.X
    row_iter2.X
    row_iter1.Y
    row_iter2.Y
    ID1 = Vector{Int64}()
    ID2 = Vector{Int64}()
    Stime1 = Vector{Int64}()
    Etime1 = Vector{Int64}()
    Stime2 = Vector{Int64}()
    Etime2 = Vector{Int64}()
    Distance = Vector{Float64}()
    X1 = Vector{Int64}()
    Y1 = Vector{Int64}()
    X2 = Vector{Int64}()
    Y2 = Vector{Int64}()
    iter1 = size(df1, 1)
    iter2 = size(df2, 1)
    lock1 = Base.Threads.SpinLock()
    Threads.@threads for i in 1:iter1
        for j in i+1:iter2
            if row_iter1.ID[i] != row_iter2.ID[j] && row_iter2.Stime[j] < row_iter1.Etime[i]
                if  euclidean([row_iter1.X[i], row_iter1.Y[i]], [row_iter2.X[j], row_iter2.Y[j]]) <= 50  
                Threads.lock(lock1)
                try
                    push!(ID1, row_iter1.ID[i])
                    ......# save some time here
                finally
                    Base.Threads.unlock(lock1)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
return DataFrame(ID1=ID1, ID2=ID2, )
end
```